# True or false: $ U^{\bot }\bot V$ then $ U\bot V^{\bot }$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

We know that:

$C(A^{T})^{\bot}=N(A) $

$N(A^{T})^{\bot}=C(A) $

C-column space, N - nullspace

How these statements can help me to prove:

$ U^{\bot }\bot V$ then $ U\bot V^{\bot }$ ?

I think it is true beacuse:

$ (U^{\bot })^{\bot }=U $

Thanks for any tip

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false. For example, consider the sets
$$
U = \{(x,y,0):x,y \in \Bbb R\}\subset \Bbb R^3, \quad V = \{(x,0,0):x \in \Bbb R\} \subset \Bbb R^3.
$$
However, the statement will hold if we have the additional fact that $\dim(U) = \dim(V)$.